# Is the K Means Algorithm supposed to be running this long?

Tags: python, algorithm, k-means

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import metrics
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('cluster.csv')

print (df.loc[:,['Location ID','Latitude','Longitude']])
x1 = np.array(df.loc[:,['Latitude']])
x2 = np.array(df.loc[:,['Longitude']])

plt.plot()
plt.xlim([0, 10])
plt.ylim([0, 10])
plt.title('Dataset')
plt.scatter(x1, x2)
plt.show()

# create new plot and data
plt.plot()
X = np.array(list(zip(x1, x2))).reshape(len(x1), 2)
colors = ['b', 'g', 'r']
markers = ['o', 'v', 's']

# k means determine k
distortions = []
K = range(1,15738)
for k in K:
    kmeanModel = KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(X)
    kmeanModel.fit(X)
    distortions.append(sum(np.min(cdist(X, kmeanModel.cluster_centers_, 'euclidean'), axis=1)) / X.shape[0])

# Plot the elbow
plt.plot(K, distortions, 'bx-')
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('Distortion')
plt.title('The Elbow Method showing the optimal k')
plt.show()
```

I am trying to find the optimal amount of clusters using the Elbow Curve. It works when I set K range to say 10, or 100. But 15,000+ is where it I have never been able to get it done. Even leaving it overnight.

So is there another method I can use to find the elbow curve?

Comment: Can you make your example minimal?

Comment: @rpoleski Not sure what you mean?

The 15,000 locations are locations of a major Store chain, and I needed to Cluster them so i can make them into sizable chunks for researching

Comment: At SO, it's best to follow [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) approach to get the answer. Most of your code seems to be not related to the question. Additionally: 1) Your doing `.fit(X)` twice - seems to be waste of time. 2) It's not clear if you have 15k datapoints or you request 15k clusters. 3) You can plot execution time vs. number of clusters to see how many you can calculate in reasonable time. 4) You can make a plot of Elbow Curve each e.g. 10 iterations of the loop to stop after reasonable time.

Comment: @rpoleski Thanks, will do! I'll try clarifying and minimizing on a new question. Actually, to my understanding, I am doing both? I do have 15K datapoints, and the elbow curve would need to plot all 15K so I can find where it platues.

Comment: No! Do not start new question for the same issue. Just edit the current question. My understanding of Elbow Curve method is that you don't have to go to the size of the sample. With huge samples it will be undoable.